# How to see which commit a branch is refering to?

Tags: git, git-branch

I would like to compare two *branches* : be able to see which *commit* they are refering to.

I read that a *branch* is just a pointer to a *commit*.  Is there a simple command to get the hash of a specific *branch* ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110478/how-to-find-the-hash-of-branch-in-git

Comment: git log <branch> gives you the last commits on that branch