# go-git: Is it possible to perform a hard reset to origin branch?

Tags: git, go, go-git

I'm trying to achieve the result of the following git commands programmatically using go-git:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/<some_branch>
```

So there's `git.Worktree.Reset()`, which gets `git.ResetOptions`, which has a `Commit` property which is of type `plumbing.Hash`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the hash for `origin/<some_branch>`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Git from the command line you'd need to use `rev-parse` (see [How to find the hash of branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110478/how-to-find-the-hash-of-branch-in-git)).

It seems to be implemented partially in go-git:

> There exists a method [(*Repository).ResolveRevision](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4#Repository.ResolveRevision) which satisfies
>   part of the behavior of `rev-parse`

Source: https://github.com/src-d/go-git/issues/599